# imageMagick: draw a text on page two of pdf

Tags: imagemagick

I was trying to add a text on pdf page 2

by the command

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -pointsize 80 -draw "text 400,550 'HeLLO'"  out.pdf
```

I can add the text on page 1.

But

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -pointsize 80 -draw "text 400,550 'HeLLO'"  out.pdf
```

Wont work on page 2.

I tried to split it and add text one by one but that is too slow.
Is there a way I can draw a text on both page 1 and 2 directly in one command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf[1] -pointsize 80 -draw "text 400,550 'HeLLO'"  out.pdf
```

Thinking about this it will only output page 2 and not the whole pdf?

Looking at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429311/creating-thumbnail-image-from-the-first-page-of-pdf you should be able to do:

```
 convert -density 300 input.pdf[0-1] -pointsize 80 -draw "text 400,550 'HeLLO'"  out.pdf
```

Comment: Is there a way I can change both page 1 and page 2 in one command?

Comment: Sorry I did not read your question properly - I am not sure as I do not use pdf files. As you are not resizing the pdf it may be better to call ghostscript directly as that is the program Imagemagick uses to work with pdf files.